# Create an array where key is unique and duplicate key's value will be sum of keys

Tags: php, arrays

I have created an array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_price] => 88.0000
            [category_id] => 13
        )

    [1] => Array
        (            
            [product_price] => 180.0000
            [category_id] => 13          
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [product_price] => 180.0000
            [category_id] => 13
        )

    [3] => Array
        (            
            [product_price] => 150.0000
            [category_id] => 13         
        )
    [4] => Array
        (            
            [product_price] => 200.0000
            [category_id] => 14            
        )        



)
```

The above array will be create only tow index(0 and 1). Here I want to remove remove duplicate arrays **category_id** wise and will add all duplicate value's **product_price**  will be add.I want to like as :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [product_price] => 598.0000
            [category_id] => 13            
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [product_price] => 200.0000
            [category_id] => 14            
        )

)
```

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: How did you create an array in which two keys are identical? The fourth key is `3` and so is the fifth key.

Comment: [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php).

Comment: @supravat have you found solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

Here `$cart` is your array name

```
$res_arr = array(); 

    foreach($cart as $p)
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach($res_arr as $k => $r)
        {
            if($r["category_id"]==$p["category_id"])
            {
                $res_arr[$k]["product_price"] += $p["product_price"];
                $found = true;
            }       
        }
        if(! $found)
            $res_arr[] = $p;
    }
    print_r($res_arr);
```

Comment: That's exactly I perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Create a map with category_id as key. Define custom insert method for map which checks that if key already exists then add product_price to old one

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you explain more about this??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code-

```
<?php
    $arr=array(
        0 => array
            (
                'product_price' => 88.0000,
                'category_id' => 13
            ),

        1 => array
            (            
                'product_price' => 180.0000,
                'category_id' => 13          
            ),

        2 => array
            (
                'product_price' => 180.0000,
                'category_id' => 13
            ),

        3 => array
            (            
                'product_price' => 150.0000,
                'category_id' => 13         
            ),
        4 => array
            (            
                'product_price' => 200.0000,
                'category_id' => 14            
            )
    );

    //logic here
    $cat_arr=array();
    $reduced_arr=array();

    //Fetching unique category_id.
    foreach($arr as $sub_arr)
    {
        if(!in_array($sub_arr['category_id'], $cat_arr))
            $cat_arr[]=$sub_arr['category_id'];
    }

    //Getting the final result
    foreach($cat_arr as $cat)
    {
        $price=0;
        foreach($arr as $prod)
        {
            if($prod['category_id']==$cat)
                $price+=$prod['product_price'];
        }
        $reduced_arr[]= array('product_price' => $price, 'category_id' => $cat);
    }

    print_r($reduced_arr);
?>
```

### O/P

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [product_price] => 598 [category_id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [product_price] => 200 [category_id] => 14 ) )
```